# Jquery wait for on event to return value

Tags: jquery

I have written a function to use as a confirmation box:

```
$.fn.confirmation = function(message, color) {

      $('.notification').css("background", color);
      $('.notification').html(message + "<br/><a href='#' id='sure'>I am sure</a> or <a href='#cancel' id='cancel'>Cancel</a>");
      $('.notification').slideDown();

      $(document).on("click", '.notification a', function(event){

        if($(this).attr("id") == "sure") {

          $('.notification').slideUp();

          return true;

        } else if($(this).attr("id") == "cancel") {

          $('.notification').slideUp();

          return false;
        }

      }); 

    };
```

My problem is that it will always return false, it doesn't even wait for the on event.

How can i force JQuery to wait for a user to click?

Comment: Why are you returning? Don't use `return`, use `event.preventDefault` or `event.stopPropagation`. Did you use any break point in firebug to figure the flow?. `return false` means the 2 above and will likely not be what you want.

Comment: @Jorge I'am checking outside the function if the user clicked on true or false to perform the action?

Comment: It won't return false, it will return undefined (which, for the purposes of an `if` statement, is the same thing) because there's no `return` statement in your `$.fn.confirmation` function. You can't force the function to wait until the user clicks because you'd end up locking up the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't returning `false`, it's returning `undefined`, since your return statements are actually in anonymous function executed when the event occurs, and not in the `confirmation` function. The easiest way (in my opinion) to solve this problem is using `deferred` objects:

```
$.fn.confirmation = function (message, color) {

    $('.notification').css("background", color);
    $('.notification').html(message + "<br/><a href='#' id='sure'>I am sure</a> or <a href='#cancel' id='cancel'>Cancel</a>");
    $('.notification').slideDown();

    var def = $.Deferred();

    $(document).on("click", '.notification a', function (event) {

        if ($(this).attr("id") == "sure") {

            $('.notification').slideUp();

            def.resolve(true);

        } else if ($(this).attr("id") == "cancel") {

            $('.notification').slideUp();

            def.resolve(false);
        }

    });

    return def.promise();
};


$.confirmation('message', 'red').done(function(result) {
   // result is true or false. 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't "wait" for the event to return. You need to pass additional parameter to your function that will be a callback:

```
$.fn.confirmation = function(message, color, callback) {
   //...
   $(document).on("click", '.notification a', function(event){
       if($(this).attr("id") == "sure") {
           $('.notification').slideUp();
           if (typeof callback === "function")
               callback(true);
       } else if($(this).attr("id") == "cancel") {
           $('.notification').slideUp();
           if (typeof callback === "function")
               callback(false);
       }
   });
}
```

And to use it:

```
$.confirmation("hello", "red", function(success) {
    if (success) {
        //...
    } else {
        //...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should modify your confirmation function to take callbacks for the `true` and `false` scenarios.

```
$.fn.confirmation = function(message, color, okCallback, cancelCallback) {
    $('.notification').css("background", color);
    $('.notification').html(message + "<br/><a href='#' id='sure'>I am sure</a> or <a href='#cancel' id='cancel'>Cancel</a>");
    $('.notification').slideDown();

    $(document).on("click", '.notification a', function(event){

      if($(this).attr("id") == "sure") {

        $('.notification').slideUp();

        okCallback();

    } else if($(this).attr("id") == "cancel") {

        $('.notification').slideUp();

        cancelCallback();
    }

  });         
}
```

Then, when you call the function create your anonymous callbacks to do what you want:

```
$('#whatever').confirmation('...', '...', function() {
    //do 'OK' stuff
}, function() {
    //do 'Cancel' stuff
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Replicating confirmation or prompt boxes in jQuery must use callbacks. Since the dialogs can't be blocking calls like the native `.confirm()` and `.prompt()`, they can't return values.

Have your consumer pass a `sureCallback` and a `cancelCallback`, then execute them when the user picks a choice. I'd also recommend using a `settings` object instead of multiple parameters:

```
$.fn.confirmation = function (settings) {
    settings = $.extend({
        message: 'default message', 
        color: 'default color', 
        sureCallback: $.noop, 
        cancelCallback: $.noop
    }, settings || {});

    $('.notification')
        .css("background", settings.color)
        .html(settings.message + "<br/><a href='#' id='sure'>I am sure</a> or <a href='#cancel' id='cancel'>Cancel</a>")
        .slideDown();

    $(document).on("click", '.notification a', function () {
        $('.notification').slideUp();

        if (this.id === "sure") {
            settings.sureCallback();
        } else {
            settings.cancelCallback();
        }
    });
};
```